# Reverse axis in a SPSS Scatterplot without using GGRAPH

Tags: graph, spss, ggraph

I want to create a grouped scatterplot in SPSS with an inversed y-axis and I am out of ideas how. The y-axis goes from 1 to 12 upwards but i would like to invert it so it goes from 1 to 12 downwards.

Using the command `GRAPH` and the subcommand  `/SCATTERPLOT` it is not possible to invert the y-axis manually.

Using the Chart Builder, which uses the command `GGRAPH`, I am able to invert the y axis (using `SCALE: cat(dim(2), reverse())`) but it messes up my scale on the x-axis, using strange numbers (e.g. 24, 31, 37, 43 instead of 20, 30, 40) which i cannot change.

Have you any ideas how to make a grouped scatterplot with an inversed y-axis or how to rescale the x-axis in `GGRAPH`? I'm rather a beginner in SPSS so some piece of code would be very helpful. Thank you for your help.

---

*Using the command `GRAPH` - Here I am not able to invert the y-axis*.

```
GRAPH
  /SCATTERPLOT(BIVAR) = V2 WITH V1 BY V3
  /MISSING=LISTWISE.
```

---

*Using the chart builder with the command `GGRAPH` - Here the chart builder uses a strange scale for the x-axis which I cannot change.*.

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=V2 V1 V3 
    MISSING=LISTWISE 
    REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE
  /FITLINE TOTAL=NO SUBGROUP=NO.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: V2=col(source(s), name("V2"), unit.category())
  DATA: V1=col(source(s), name("V1"), unit.category())
  DATA: V3=col(source(s), name("V3"), unit.category())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("V2"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("V1"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("V3"))
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Gruppiertes Streudiagramm  von V1  Schritt: V2 Schritt: ",
    "V3"))
  SCALE: cat(dim(2), reverse())
  ELEMENT: point(position(V2*V1), color.interior(V3))
END GPL.
```

Comment: I now also tried the command: 
`SCALE: linear(dim(1), min (20), max (140))`  
to change the scale of the x-axis in the `GGRAPH` command but the error "Cannot combine category and number types for items 'V2' and 'null' occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing your data, I would expect one of the following [examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/gpl/gpl_function_reverse.html) from the SPSS Statistics Documentation to achieve the result you're after  (at least for reversing the axis).

I hope this helps

-ddwyer

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).